# Using lapply for multiple lists in a function

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply, mapply

I have 2 lists of matrices A and B:

```
n<-10
generate<-function (n){
matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10) 
}
A<-lapply(1:n, generate)
B<-lapply(1:n, generate)
```

I am trying to use lapply to run it through a function with two inputs. Where my function is a function I have created`ABC()`:

```
ABC(x,y)
```

I now try to run the lists A for x and B for y by using lapply:

```
l<-lapply(A,B, ABC(x,y))
```

This does not work as it recognises B as a function instead of a list that should be associated with y. Do I need to use `sapply` or `mapply`and if so how?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried `mapply`?

Comment: Your function `generate` takes `n` as an input, but it does not use `n` anywhere in the function.

Comment: @Dirty Sock Sniffer when using `mapply` I get the following `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'b' of mode 'function' was not found`. @bouncyball that is not my problem it is the lapply bit.

Comment: @adaodante  `mapply(x = A, y = B, FUN = function(x, y) ABC(x, y))`

Comment: @bouncyball thank you the `mapply(x = A, y = B, FUN = function(x, y) ABC(x, y))` has worked thanks again.

Comment: @adaodante see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega?rq=1) for more information on the `*apply` family of functions

Comment: @bouncyball `FUN = function(x, y) ABC(x, y)` is doubly redundant. Simply write `FUN = ABC`. Furthermore, the function is the first parameter in `mapply`, so you can simply write `mapply(ABC, A, B)`.

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to achieve but the code that you’ve written can be shortened drastically by using `replicate(10, matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10))`. This replaces the first four lines of your script. You can use it twice to generate `A` and `B`.

Answer (score -1):

mapply is what you looking for?

```
n<-10
generate<-function (n){
  matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10) 
}
A<-lapply(1:n, generate)
B<-lapply(1:n, generate)


mapply(generate, c( 1:n,1:n))
```

Comment: That doesn’t do what you think, it will simply call `generate` 20 times.

Comment: You are right, I guess I didn't get the question. @adaodante got the answer.